# What is the best way to determine when a WatchOS 2 app is opened?

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos-2

willActivate seems to be called in a few different situations and can be called multiple times?
didAppear is only called once when the app is started?

I just want a function to be called when the user opens the app no matter if the app is being awoken from the background or not. Any good solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [WKExtensionDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKExtensionDelegate_protocol/index.html) protocol.

Override `applicationDidBecomeActive` and `applicationWillResignActive` to manage active state your self.

Comment: applicationDidBecomeActive works great when the app is running! I supplement it with awakeWithContext in the InterfaceController. Thanks!